# Какие способы есть чтобы хукнуть функцию .rodata в unix

Tags: c++, unix

Есть файл

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped
```

Какие способы есть чтобы хукнуть функцию по адресу .rodata:083619B4 чтобы в дальнейшем блокировать вызов при некоторых агрументах.

Comment: Поизучайте [ptrace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html). Дебаггеры применяют его для изменений в отлаживаемой программе